# Use no dominance to show that the price of the call option satisfies the inequality

Tags: finance, mathematics, finance-mathematics

Assumption 2.1 - If the payoff $P$ of a financial instrument is non negative, then the price $p$ of the financial instrument is non negative.

Assume $C$ is just the price of the call option, and $C^{*}$ is also the price of a different call option with the same parameters as $C$ except that $\tau = T - t$ where $T$ is the maturity and $t$ is current time

Assume no dominance, Assumption 2.1. Show that the price of call option should satisfy $$(S - B_t(T)K)_+ \leq C(T,K,S)\leq C^{*}(T,K,S)\leq S$$ Therefore, for any price quote $C^{*}(\tau,K,S)$ of a call option with strike $K$ and time to maturity $\tau$, there exists a unique $\sigma^{imp}(\tau,K,S)$ such that $$C(\tau,K,S,\sigma^{imp},r) = C^{*}(\tau,K,S)$$ $\sigma^{imp}(\tau,K,S)$ is called implied volatility. See figure below[image: figure]

Attempted proof: Let the price of a call option with strike $K$ be denoted $C(K)$. Assume when we purchase a call option the stock price $S$ is equal to the strike price $K$. Hence we have $$C(T,K,S)\leq S$$ at time $T$.

I am not really sure where to go from here, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to define the notations. For example, what are $L$, $C$, $C^*$, and what is the difference between $C^*(T, K,S)$ and $C^*(\tau, K,S)$?

Comment: @Gordon Sorry some typos one second

Comment: @Gordon I fixed the typos to the question

Comment: In this sense, I will assume that $C(T,K,S)=C^*(T,K,S)$, while $C^*(\tau, K, S)$ is just a different notation for $C^*(T,K,S)$. That is, they are all the same.

Comment: @Gordon could you see my new question I posted its right up your alley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(S_T-K)^+ -S_T  \le 0$, By the dominance principle,
\begin{align*}
0 &\ge E\left(\frac{S_T-K)^+ -S_T}{e^{rT}}\right)\\
&= E\left(\frac{S_T-K)^+}{e^{rT}}\right) -  E\left(\frac{S_T}{e^{rT}}\right)\\
&=C(T, K, S)-S.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
C(T, K, S) \le S. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, since 
\begin{align*}
(S_T-K)^+ -(S_T-K)\ge 0,
\end{align*}
by the dominance principle, 
\begin{align*}
E\left(\frac{(S_T-K)^+ -(S_T-K)}{e^{rT}}\right) \ge 0.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
C(T, K, S) &\ge S-e^{-rT}K.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Moreover, since 
\begin{align*}
(S_T-K)^+ \ge 0,
\end{align*}
by the dominance principle again,
\begin{align*}
C(T, K, S) &\ge 0.\tag{3}
\end{align*}
In summary, from (1)-(3),
\begin{align*}
\big(S-e^{-rT}K\big)^+ \le C(T, K, S) \le S.
\end{align*}
Here, for a given volatility $\sigma$,
\begin{align*}
C(T, K, S)(\sigma) &= S\Phi(d_1)-e^{-rT} K \Phi(d_2),
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
d_1= \frac{\ln\frac{S}{e^{-rT}K }+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}},
\end{align*} 
and 
\begin{align*}
d_2= \frac{\ln\frac{S}{e^{-rT}K}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}},
\end{align*}
is a continuous function of $\sigma$. It is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow +\infty}C(T, K, S)(\sigma) = S,
\end{align*} 
and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0+}C(T, K, S)(\sigma) = \big(S-e^{-rT}K\big)^+.
\end{align*}
Therefore, for any value $C^*$ that satisfies
\begin{align*}
\big(S-e^{-rT}K\big)^+ < C^* < S,
\end{align*}
there is a volatility, which we denote by $\sigma^{imp}$, such that
\begin{align*}
C(T, K, S)(\sigma^{imp}) = C^*.
\end{align*}

Comment: Any chance you could revise this to include the no dominance principle

Comment: @MorganWeiss: I do not know the no dominance principle. You may need to provide some background information.

Comment: I did I have the definition of it, it's called assumption 2.1. Do you see it?